# Simple JSON file with just one Array to get on my Android App

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have a JSON file with just one Array as in this example (as you see this array doesn't have a name):

> `["Cream","Cheese","Milk","Powder Milk","Blue Cheese","Gouda Cheese"]`

How can I just get this array into an array or an arraylist in my Android Studio?

Thank you so much in advance!

Here is a function that I am creating to get this array yet I can't complete it I am still a noob with handling json files.

```
    public void getProducts() {


    JsonArrayRequest myresponseArray = new JsonArrayRequest(url,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try {

                        for(int i = 0 ; i < response.length();i++){

                            JSONArray responseArray = response.getJSONArray(i);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });


}
```

Now I want to add this "responseArray" into my products array list that I created on the MainActivity

```
ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Read the Title its about JSON. And the String posted is not JSON Thats makes it unclear . seems a case of `String#split()`.

Comment: Is the value of your `JSONArray response` the one you've posted?

Comment: @Prexx The one I posted is the values in my JSON file, I want to transfer these values to my arraylist called "products".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `geString(int index)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < responeArray.length(); i++) {
   products.add( responseArray.getString(i) );
}
```

Comment: You are the boss! I just took the response directly with getString as the response was already an array as in `products.add( response.getString(i) );` Thank you so much.